# Python Tkinter: Buttons not scrollable

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a question regarding placed buttons on a frame!

I created a canvas and placed a frame inside this canvas! Inside the canvas I place rectangles and oder stuff, drawn by tkinters canvas.create_rectangle, whereas I place certain widgets like buttons inside the frame. (Result: There are togehter in one window)

```
window_canvas = Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="grey", width = window_canvas_size[0], height = window_canvas_size[1], highlightthickness=0)

window_frame = Frame(window_canvas, background='white', borderwidth=0, width = canvas_size[0], height = canvas_size[1])
```

Now I made the window_canvas scrollable via:

```
def OnMousewheelConfigureProcessCanvas(self, event):
    window_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

window_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", m.OnMousewheelConfigureProcessCanvas)
```

The buttons are scrollable with the window_canvas, when I place the cursor outside of them, no problem.
However, when I hover with my mouse cursor above a button, the "scrollability" just doesn't work anymore. The window_canvas doesn't react to the mouse wheel this time.

I dont want to create a new window (via canvas.create_window) for every button. I have quite a few of them on screen, so I tried to keep it simple by placing one frame for all inside a canvas!

Looking forward to your solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Windows/Linux/MacOS?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example?

Comment: Bind on `root` instead of `window_canvas`?

Comment: root binding did the trick! Thank you!